# Is there a max size for images being loaded onto canvas on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, image, canvas, image-size

I am building a webapp game that has a scrolling background. The background is just a really tall image that is copied to the smaller `canvas` in slices to give the sensation of movement. The image file I started with was 6000px tall (my canvas is 640px tall). All desktop browsers and iPad2 (iOS 6) loaded the image file fine and the animation looks great.

However, on iPhone 4S (iOS 5) - the background never loads at all! I solved the problem  by just cutting the big background image down until it was under 2000px tall, and there the iPhone finally loaded the graphics onto the canvas and everything works great from there.

So my question is - is there a maximum file size that the javascript `canvas.context` can handle? Maybe just on certain devices?

I tried all kinds of other work arounds to ensure the file was completely loaded before the JS code ran on the canvas, to no avail.